# Where to put custom functions in Zend Framework 1.10

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have to use custom functions / objects in my web application based on Zend Framework 1.10.
Where is the best place to put them ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends on what they do. Can you tell us?

Comment: *(related)* [Does Zend framework has a fix version of file structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536332/does-zend-framework-has-a-fix-version-of-file-structure/2536394) and [Where to put plugins in a Zend Framework website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400772/where-to-put-plugins-in-a-zend-framework-website/2400796)

Comment: An exemple for objects I use : 
In a house, they is many cabinets: house contains rooms. Each rooms contains cabinets.

For functions : getMeanValueFromArray, getStdDevFromArray ...

I hope this will clarify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects you describe belong to the Model, so they go in `application/models`. Remember that the Model is everything that is not pertaining to the presentation layer (e.g. the V and C in MVC). My suggestion would be to have this structure then:

```
application
- models
-- my            -> to indicate this is yours
--- persistence  -> contains all classes that capsulte Data access logic
--- domain       -> business objects in your domain of application
--- service      -> services that use the domain objects or the persistence layer
--- mappers      -> your ORM layer (unless you are not using Doctrine anyway)
```

If you have classes that are generic enough to be reused in other applications, you can place them into the /lib folder. But everything specifically made for your app should go in models.

Also, have a look at the [ZFPlanet Sample Project by Padraic Brady](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet)

Comment: How can I access to those objects / functions in a Controller ?

Thanks ?

Comment: @user just like you would access your other model classes too. Follow the Zend Naming Convention and the autoloader should take care of the rest.

Comment: Actually the default resource autoloader specifies a number of different directories under `/application` to store different classes, e.g. `/application/services`, `/application/plugins`, `/application/forms`, etc. ZF seems to consider the `/application/models` dir as the place to store business domain object classes and DAL classes. This is a slightly different interpretation of what is the 'model', but does leave us at a loss when trying to decide where, for example, to put a custom auth adapter.

Comment: @Richard please note that my answer was given in July '10 and reflects ZF at that time (or more likely a previous version, since I do not upgrade immediately). For any practical purpose it doesnt matter where you put it, as long as you are consistent about it and the autoloader can find it.