# Passing value from controller to layout

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have tried to pass a value from controller to layout using this but it does not work:

```
foreach ($user_info_details as $details):
    $first_name = $details['first_name'];
endforeach;
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->assign('first_name',$first_name);
```

and retrieve it using

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->first_name; ?>
```

but it shows blank in every case

Answer (score 3):

To output values to your view easily, in your controller use:

```
$this->view->first_name = $first_name;
```

And in your view, access it like this:

```
echo $this->first_name;
```

Comment: i know this but this will create redundancy .. i want to send the value from controller to laypout

Comment: This will help you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537700/sending-variables-to-the-layout-in-zend-framework