# Zend Framework 2 - Make content page variable accessable in layout.phtml

Tags: variables, zend-framework2, layout-page

I want to build a fancy headline container which - you'll never guess it - contains the title of each page displayed.

In `Django` you can either create a variable in every view which is passed to the layout page or define a block which is filled with content on the content page.

Its not such a nice solution copy and pasting my fancy header on every page of my application just to put my page title in. I'd prefer to put the headline container in my layout page and use my `$title` variable to set the title within the container.

I found a solution for static variables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537700/sending-variables-to-the-layout-in-zend-framework) but I need a dynamic variable because the title is different for every page.

My question: Is there an easy way to pass the `$title` variable which I have on every content page to my layout.phtml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is quite simple if you know what to look for. Use the [placeholder helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#placeholder-helper).

```
//layout.phtml
<?php $this->placeholder('foo')->set("Some text for later") ?>
```

and

```
//myview.phtml
<?php
   echo $this->placeholder('foo');
   // outputs "Some text for later"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice view Helper in ZF for this task. You can define what Title you want to use for your page in your view files.

In your view pages:

```
//index.tmpl
$this->headTitle("this is my unique title for this page");
```

In your Layout file :

```
<title><?php echo $this->headTitle() ?></title>
```

And more info at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-title.html

Comment: I use this `headTitle()` function but AFAIK its for the title tag as you outlined. I want a regular div to be a headline for my content, just like a `<h1>` tag. Because my title is more code than just <h1> I'd like to put it centerally into the layout - if possible.

Comment: Have a look at ZF Placeholders then.