# Controller won't pass a variable in View for Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

So I started to learn Zend Framework 1 and run in to some problem, with passing a values in a View. I created a simple variable in IndexContoller like this:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->content = "Lorem ipsum";
    }


}
```

And then I called it in a layout like this:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h2><?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?></h2>
</div>
```

It returns nothing, when I do var dump

```
var_dump($this->layout()->content)
```

I get this back:

```
string(0) ""
```

How to fix this?

Comment: it's just $this->content not $this->layout()->content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `$this->layout()->content` should be used in your layout to render the output that has been generated in your action specific view.  Typically many action specific `.phtml` files will use a [common layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.layout.usage.html).

If you want to pass something from the controller to the view you would use `$this->foo = 'bar'` on the controller then render it in your view with `echo $this->foo`;

I've also found this existing post that might answer your question: [Sending variables to the layout in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537700/sending-variables-to-the-layout-in-zend-framework) - It explains the overlap and commonalities of the layout and view.  Up to you if you feel that is a dupe...

Answer (score 0):

ZF1 uses the variable `content` to capture the result of the view and pass to the layout. I'm guessing your `index.phtml` view is empty which is why you're getting an empty string from `$this->layout()->content`.

If you want to pass some data to the layout, assign it to the view object as normal, but *call it anything other than 'content'*:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->foo = "Lorem ipsum";
}
```

then in your layout, access it like you would a normal view variable:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h2><?php echo $this->foo; ?></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with ficuscr's answer.

However if you *really* need to set some layout's value from a controller this ugly hack may work for you:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->foo = "value";
```